# Add integers to a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to ask the user for several values for temperatures of several month by the "monthtemp" input and then add all the values to a list and in the end print out the average for the whole year.

```
count = 1

loops = int(input("How many years?: "))
listofmonthtemperatures= list()
while count < loops:
for i in range(1,loops+1):
    count += 1
    year = input("Which is the " + str(i) + ": year?: ")
    for j in range (1,13):
        monthtemp= int(input("Month " + str(j) + ": "))
        listofmonthtemperatures.append(monthtemp)



total= sum(listofmonthtemperatures)
averagetempforyear= total / 12
print("The average temperature for", year, "is", averagetempforyear)
```

But I get the message year is not defined, but haven't I defined it as whatever the user inputs? And second, will this work? Why can't append simply append the value to listofmonthtemperatures?

Comment: Initialize the year variable at the beginning of you code below `count = 1 year = 0` (The year is a local variable and it is accessible in the scope of you outher for loop)

Comment: Ok, now it works if I ask for more than one year in the "loops" but if I write 1 it just prints the average temp for 0 is 0.00? @C1sc0

Comment: Replace your monthtemp variable wiht a list and append the month tempreature variables to them, after that you will be able to get the average temperature / year (aslo write a loop at the end of you code where you get the right month  values from the `listofmonthtemperatures`) For example: `AvgTemp = sum(listofmonthtemperatures[0]) / 12 # first year avg temp etc.`

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your code and it worked just fine. Maybe this was a typo but your for loops weren't properly indented. I'm running 3.4.3 btw.

```
count = 1
loops = int(input("How many years?: "))
listofmonthtemperatures= list()
while count < loops:
    for i in range(1,loops+1):
        count += 1
        year = input("Which is the " + str(i) + ": year?: ")
        for j in range (1,13):
            monthtemp= int(input("Month " + str(j) + ": "))
            listofmonthtemperatures.append(monthtemp)

total= sum(listofmonthtemperatures)
averagetempforyear= total / 12
print("The average temperature for", year, "is", averagetempforyear)
```

Above is the working code with the proper indentation.